# Problema ao fazer encode e decode de String

Tags: java, string, codificação-de-caracteres, java-8

Gostaria de saber porque que tais métodos não se comportam de forma que:

> long2str(str2long(String s)) == String s

```
   public long[] str2long(String s){
        final byte[] authBytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authBytes);
        long[] array = new long[encoded.length()];
        int i=0;
        for(char c: encoded.toCharArray()){
            array[i] = (long) c;
//             System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
             i++;
        }
        return array;
    }
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------

```
public String long2str(long[] array){
    char[] chArray = new char[array.length];
    int i=0;
    for(long c: array){
        chArray[i] = (char) c;
        i++;
    }
    String s = Arrays.toString(chArray);
    final byte[] decoded= Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
    try {
        s = new String(decoded, "UTF-8");
        return s;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Encryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Pelo que me parece estou fazendo correto, não seria só inverter a ordem dos passos para conseguir tal efeito?

Comment: Se você imprimir `long2str(str2long(String s))`, ele é igual à `String s`?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 5b`

Já estou investigando...

Answer (score 2):

O seu método `long2str` está errado:

```java
    String s = Arrays.toString(chArray);
```

Isso daí não faz o que você quer. Por exemplo:

```java
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2long("Hello World")));
```

Mostra isso:

```plain
[83, 71, 86, 115, 98, 71, 56, 103, 86, 50, 57, 121, 98, 71, 81, 61]
```

E isso não é uma `String` base-64 válida.

O que você queria é isso:

```java
    String s = new String(chArray);
```

Testei aqui com essa correção, e funcionou perfeitamente.